# finding occurrences in Multiple sentences

Tags: python, frequency

I'm new to python however after scouring the internet and going back over my study, I cannot seem to find how to find duplicates of a word within multiple sentences. my aim is to define how many times the word python occurs within these strings. I have tried the split() method and count.(python) and even tried to make a dictionary and word_counter which initially I have been taught to do as part of the basics however nothin in my study has shown me anything similar to this before. i need to be able to display the frequency of the word. python occurs 4 times. any help would be very appreciated

python_occurs = ["welcome to our Python program", "Python is my favorite language!", "I am afraid of Pythons", "I love Python"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight-forward approach is to iterate over every word using `split`. For each word, it's converted to lowercase and the number of times `"python"` occurs in it is counted using `count`.

I guess the reason for you approach not working might be that you forgot to change the letters to lowercase.

```
python_occurs = ["welcome to our Python program", "Python is my favorite language!", "I am afraid of Pythons", "I love Python"]
count = 0
for sentence in python_occurs:
    for word in sentence.split():
        # lower is necessary because we want to be case-insensitive
        count += word.lower().count("python")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, i fixed this another way without lowering the case.
i used this method
 def find_occurrences(text, itemsList):
    occurs = 0
    for i in text:
        occurs += i.count(itemsList)
    return occurs
print(find_occurrences(['welcome to our Python program', 'Python is my favourite language!','I am afraid of Pythons', 'I love Python'], 'Python'))